# What best practice to call requests if no connection - repeat call every 4-5 seconds until we get response, use Rx

Tags: android, kotlin, system.reactive, rx-java2

For example we have some methods

```
private fun getMobileData() {
        apiClient.getMobileData()
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .subscribe({ result ->
                datasBehavior.onNext(result.datas)
                actionsBehavior.onNext(result.actions)
            }) { it.message }.addTo(subscriptions)
    }
```

what best and easiest way for make **use RX** if no connextion repeat call every 4-5 seconds until we get response

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use `retryWhen`.

```
private fun getMobileData() {
    apiClient.getMobileData()
        .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
        .retryWhen { error -> 
            error.flatMap { Observable.timer(4, TimeUnit.SECONDS) }
        }
        .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
        .subscribe({ result ->
            datasBehavior.onNext(result.datas)
            actionsBehavior.onNext(result.actions)
        }) { it.message }.addTo(subscriptions)
}
```

And if you want to check the error is caused exactly by no connection, you can do it in `error.flatMap{}` block like `if(it is NoConnectionException)`.

Comment: I imagine it's the same on Java as C# so you should always move your `subscribeOn` and `observeOn` to as late in the pipeline as possible.

Comment: @Enigmativity thanks for comment. I've fixed my answer for `observeOn` being in after `retryWhen`

Answer (score 1):

For this purpose you could use this

```
source.retryWhen(errors -> errors.flatMap(error -> Observable.timer(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS)))
```

the `retryWhen` code will run if you get and error, until you receive an `onSuccess`

in your code, it would be something like:

```
private fun getMobileData() {
    apiClient.getMobileData()
        .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
        .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
        .retryWhen(e -> e.flatMap(error -> Observable.timer(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS))
        .subscribe({ result ->
            datasBehavior.onNext(result.datas)
            actionsBehavior.onNext(result.actions)
        }) { it.message }.addTo(subscriptions)
}
```

Comment: I imagine it's the same on Java as C# so you should always move your `subscribeOn` and `observeOn` to as late in the pipeline as possible.